# Wait Until Previous Command Completes

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

I have written a bash script on my MacMini to execute anytime a file has completed downloading.  After the file download is complete, the mac mounts my NAS, renames the file, and then copies the file from the mac to the NAS, deletes the file from the mac and then unmounts the NAS.

My issue is, sometimes, the NAS takes a few seconds to mount.  When that happens, I receive an error that the file could not be copies because the directory doesn’t exist.

When the NAS mounts instantly, (if the file size is small), the file copies and then the file deletes and the NAS unmounts.

When the file size is large, the copying process stops when the file is deleted.

What I’m looking for is, how do I make the script “wait” until the NAS is mounted, and then how do I make the script again wait until the file copying is complete?

Thank you for any input. Below is my code.

```sh
#connect to NAS
open 'smb://username:password@ip_address_of_NAS/folder_for_files'

#I WANT A WAIT COMMAND HERE SO THAT SCRIPT DOES NOT CONTINUE UNTIL NAS IS MOUNTED

#move to folder where files are downloaded
cd /Users/account/Downloads

#rename files and copy to server
for f in *; do
    newName="${f/)*/)}";
    mv "$f"/*.zip "$newName".zip;
    cp "$newName".zip /Volumes/folder_for_files/"$newName".zip;
    
    #I NEED SCRIPT TO WAIT HERE UNTIL FILE HAS COMPLETED ITS TRANSFER

    rm -r "$f";
done

#unmount drive
diskutil unmount /Volumes/folder_for_files
```

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't already wait until the copy is complete.

Comment: You could try adding `sync;sync;sync` after the `cp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no longer a mac to try this, but it seems `open 'smb://...'` is the only command here that does not wait for completion, but does the actual work in the background instead.

The best way to fix this would be to use something other than `open` to mount the NAS drive. According to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303595) the following should work, but due to the lack of a mac and NAS I cannot test it.

```
# replace `open ...` with this
osascript <<< 'mount volume "smb://username:password@ip_address_of_NAS"'
```

If that does not work, use this workaround which manually waits until the NAS is mounted.

```
open 'smb://username:password@ip_address_of_NAS/folder_for_files'
while [ ! -d /Volumes/folder_for_files/ ]; do sleep 0.1; done
# rest of the script
```

Comment: Was just about to post this, but with an `until` loop. Also there's probably a better way to do it with some samba utilities, but this should definitely work.

Comment: Thank you!  The while loop ended up working.  For some reason though, the script continues after it begins the copying of the file; therefore, the unmount throws errors due to the drive being in use by terminal. So I added another while loop for the unmount to keep trying until it does, and then put the removing of the files after and it all works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a loop to sleep and then for five seconds for example, and then run `smbstatus` and if the output contains any string to identify your `smb://username:password@ip_address_of_NAS/folder_for_files` connection`
when this is found to then start the copying of your files. You could also have a counter variable to stop, after certain number of times to sleep and then check if the connection has been successful too.